# Multivariable Differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given $w=-x^2+y^2-2z^2$ and $z=-2x^2-2y^2$ I am asked to find
$(\frac{\partial w}{\partial y})_z$, $(\frac{\partial w}{\partial z})_x$, and $(\frac{\partial w}{\partial z})_y$. Please help! I understand how to get partial derivatives, however, I don't understand what this is asking.

Comment: What is it exactly that you don't understand?

Comment: I'm getting $\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}$ as  $2y$ I don't understand how to get $(\frac{\partial w}{\partial y})_z$

Comment: @kingW3 Any suggestions?

Comment: As I know the $_z$ is used to denote that in that expression $z$ is constant hence $\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}=(\frac{\partial w}{\partial y})_z$.Though I'm not sure,someone with more knowledge will probably explain.

Comment: The problem is, using variables as subscripts in this fashion is used with multiple meanings. Without knowing what your text has defined, I don't know for sure which meaning is intended. As kingW3 has mentioned, it sometimes means that the variable is being held constant. But another common meaning is partial differentiation with respect to that variable. You will need to reference your text to see how it defines this notation.